# Console logs in GWT do not appear in Chrome Driver during tests

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

In GWT, I use the following method to display debug messages in my web browser console:

```
Log.debug("@@@ Debug");
```

I am running some tests with Chrome Driver, and I am printing the content of the console with the following method:

```
public static void displayConsoleContent() {
    LogEntries logs = getWebDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

    System.out.println("Console content:\n--------------------------------------------------");
    for (LogEntry log: logs.getAll()) {
        System.out.println("* " + log.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
}
```

When I manually go to the web page where the debug message is supposed to appear, it is correctly displayed in the console.

However, when I print the content of the console during the test, the message does not appear (I am getting other messages from other sources, though).

This is how I set up my Web Driver:

```
private static void setUpChrome() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/chromedriver");

        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
        loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);

        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);
    }
```

Why isn't the debug message appearing in the console when using the Chrome Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development I use GWT.log, it's very convenient and gets optimized out at runtime. Works charms for me.

```
static void     log(java.lang.String message)
static void     log(java.lang.String message, java.lang.Throwable e)
```

> Logs a message to the development shell logger in Development Mode, or
>   to the console in Super Dev Mode.

Docs: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#log-java.lang.String-

On the other hand if you run compiled code the GWT.log will be optimized out.

A quick and dirty alternative is to log straight into console with an ugly JSNI (that you can make prettier in the future if it works).

```
public static final native void log(Object o) /*-{
     console.log(o);
}-*/;
```

That should do it

Comment: This give me the same results. See my answer.

Comment: I did not noticed your Jan 12 edit, but the solution of using a JSNI worked. The issue was indeed the optimization that remove `GWT.log` call in production mode.

Comment: If you want to improve on that (and on JS libraries and API interaction in general) you should take a look at Js Interop and Elemental2.